# Export Checklist as report

Tags: autodesk-bim360, workato

With workato, I have automated several processes around BIM360. My newest job is, to automate the export the completed checklists as a report. I have tried to use the endpoint uses bei the WebUI. It seems like it is forbidden...

```
403 Forbidden: { "developerMessage":"The client_id specified does not have access to the api product", "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", "errorCode": "AUTH-001"}
```

Has anyone a good idea how to export those checklists without building an own report?
@autodesk: it would be very helpful, to release the report feature as well for the API.

Thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is not yet a direct endpoint to export records (issue/checklist/rfi) etc. May I know which endpoint you tried to call? It sounds you called an url of Checklist webpage from Network tracking in browser console?

Currently, only GET Checklist Instances/Templates are available. From API perspective, the records are not extracted by one call. The records may have huge number of items. The code will need to extract page by page. e.g. maximum to dump Issues is 200 items/page if 3rd Forge developer uses the endpoint. So if there are 1000 issues, the code will have to run 5 times. So, the actions of Wokato will need to build a loop condition.

In addition, I am curious on ‘report’ in the context. Workato builds the connection among apps. May I know which app you will connect, and does it render data as a report? At the beginning, it sounds you tried with an url of webpage function, but it looks it exports to a PDF. Even if it is possible to get the PDF within Workato, I am thinking how you use it with other apps when defining the actions.

One more thing: there is one product feature [Data Connector](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Insight/files/BIM360D-Insight-data-extractor-html-html.html) in Account level. It exports data of admin data and projects data. There is a plan an API of Data Connector may probably be exposed in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Yes, I tried to use the endpoint used by the WebUI: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/reports/v1/containers/:container_id:/reports to generate the report.

If there is no feature from autodesk to do that on automation level, my plan to create a report is as follows:
- collect data with workato and load it to an ftp server (meta in xml, images)
=> I'm used to paging in autodesk/workato (no issue)
- create an exe with C#/pdfSharp, to collect the data on the ftp and create the report.

But there are some disadvantages, like the signatures can not be exported.